# Row major order storage to multidimensional array

Tags: c

Given a 2x3 array, 
 [1,2,3]
 [4,5,6]
it is easy to store this linearly using row major order storage -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]

A particular row, column in the multidimensional array can be converted into a index in this linear array using the formula:
index = row*NumCol + column

Is there a way to compute the row,column given some index in the linear array.
So given index=1, value 2 in the linear array, is there a way to determine that row=0 column=1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple:

```
row = index / NumCol;
col = index % NumCol
```

Answer (score 0):

To go back from the 1D index to a 2D one, just divide and take the remainder.

```
twoDrow = index / COLUMNS;
twoDCol = index % COLUMNS;
```